# Genre of "Peppertones - Close up the world"

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists, style, genre-characteristics

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zl5dcwtgSVI

I am trying to find more songs with this rhythm (drum and bass) and arrangement style.

Can you help me figure out what songs/genres have used similar licks, chord progression, the arrangement style used in the intro and throughout the song?

Answer (score 1):

**This is Indie Pop**, a style that developed in the mid 90s and was big in the early 2000s.  You can still find a lot of it, but not generally on the radio. Here's a brief history of it:

In the 80s, the dominant pop sound was highly produced, and filled with synthesizers, power guitars, saxophones and drum machines.  In reaction, new styles came into style in the 90s --alternative rock, and grunge --that prized authenticity, and had a low-fi, gritty sound, and less processed vocals and instruments.  Indie Pop came just a little later.  It had **some of the same aesthetic, but with a lighter, more melodic, crowd-pleasing sound that took inspiration from 60s & 70s "power pop".** The name "Peppertones", echoing the classic Beatles album "Sgt Pepper", suggests that this band might have similar influences.

Here's the [Dave Matthews Band](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gXuYFih6Y8).
Here's [Fountains of Wayne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kq8ZzZDjTd4).
Here's [Phantom Planet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wq-S8CIU7VA).
Here's [the Shins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoLTPcD1S4Q).
Here's [Supergrass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQbVyWED6Ac).
Here's a random mix I found by googling ["Indie Pop"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUpEErpDAUo).

It's worth noting that the last part of "Close up the World" is **the theme song to the classic 80s video game *Super Mario Bros*.**